# For gawk, how to set FS and RS in the same command as an awk script?

Tags: awk

I have an awk command that returns the duplicates in an input stream with

`awk '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}'`

However, I want to change the field separator characters and record separator characters before I do that. The command I use for that is

`FS='\n' RS='\n\n'`

Yet I'm having trouble making that happen. Is there a way to effectively combine these two commands into one? Piping one to the other doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why do you want to change the FS or RS when your script doesn't use FS at all and other than for empty lines immediately after non-empty lines, won't change behavior when RS is `\n` or `\n\n`? If you provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: @jas By setting `RS` to `""`, `ORS`  is NOT modified which I guess is worth noting. So to preserve the file structure, the op might need something like `BEGIN{ORS=RS RS;RS=""}` supposing a blank line is the record separator.

Comment: @jas setting `RS=""` doesn't treat `FS` as `"\n"`. You need to manually set `FS="\n"` if that's what you want. What setting `RS=""` does do wrt FS is **add** "\n" to the set of field separators **if** FS was just one char. So if you were using the default FS that would have no effect since `\n` is already one of the chars included in the default FS's "contiguous white space" char set but if you were using `FS=","` then setting `RS=""` would make your script behave as if you had specified `FS="[,\n]"` instead. If you were using `FS=",,"` then it'd be unchanged by `RS=""`. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: Thanks as always, @EdMorton, sorry to all for the misinformation [:face-palm:].

Comment: @EdMorton Is this a GNU feature (one character vs multiple)? Posix clearly states **always**.

Comment: @EdMorton I was referring to what you wrote about `FS` : _What setting RS="" does do wrt `FS` is add "\n" to the set of field separators **if `FS` was just one char**._  While POSIX does not mention anything about `FS` being a single character or not. It just states that `\n` is always a field separator if `RS=""`, disregarding how many characters `FS` has.

Comment: @kvantour Interesting. POSIX does say that `\n` should always be added but both GNU awk (even with the `--posix` flag) and OSX/BSD awk behave the way I described. I don't have any other awks handy to test on but if anyone else does then feel free to try `printf '1::2\n3\n' | awk -F'::' -v RS= '{print NF}'` (output will be 3 if `\n` is included in FS, 2 otherwise) and let us know the result. I'm going to discuss with the provider of gawk, Arnold Robbins, and get back to you. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kvantour FWIW here's the relevant section from the gawk manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line): `When RS is set to the empty string *and* FS is set to a single character, the newline character always acts as a field separator. This is in addition to whatever field separations result from FS` with this footnote: `When FS is the null string ("") or a regexp, this special feature of RS does not apply. It does apply to the default field separator of a single space: ‘FS = " "’.`

Comment: @kvantour - from Arnold: `This smells like a change in the POSIX
standard, but I will have to research previous standards and also
what the original AWK book says.`. When he gets back to me again I'll try to remember to get back to you but feel free to remind me in a few days if you haven't heard back from me on this.

Comment: @kvantour - we have a resolution: gawk will stay as is, it's behavior will be documented in the gawk manual, and the gawk provider will work to get the POSIX spec changed to match how gawk behaves (which is more useful than the behavior POSIX describes which makes it impossible lo simply use FS as `:`, say, and include newlines inside fields when RS is null as you can do with `gawk -F'[:]' -v RS=""`). See the posts between he and I in the thread that starts at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-04/msg00029.html.

Answer (score 2):

the action of `BEGIN` rule is executed before reading any input.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="\n\n"}{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}'
```

or you can specify them using command line options like:

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS='\n\n' '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}'
```

Comment: By hardcoding `\n` you have made  your `awk` script tightly coupled to your platform.

Comment: @sjsam not me, OP did it